# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on my android app but I have no idea why

Tags: android, android-manifest

I've been trying to get started with Android programming for a while now. I'm mainly a .NET developer with no Java experience for 8 years (university).

I can compile and run samples no problem but the moment I try and rename my package/class it fails. I believe I've updated the manifest and triple checked it (Copied and pasted name, selected it with Eclipse) yet it always fails with a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

```
12-02 09:12:21.088: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.anddev.cheesemp.helloandworld/org.anddev.cheesemp.helloandworld.HelloAndEngine}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.anddev.cheesemp.helloandworld.HelloAndEngine in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43d0c0d0
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.anddev.cheesemp.helloandworld.HelloAndEngine in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43d0c0d0
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
12-02 09:12:21.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     ... 11 more
```

Manifest is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

          android:versionCode="1"

          android:versionName="1.0" package="org.anddev.cheesemp.helloandworld">

          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

            <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="org.anddev.cheesemp.helloandworld.HelloAndEngine">

                <intent-filter>

                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                </intent-filter>

            </activity>

        </application>

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" \>

    </manifest>
```

Class definition is here:

```
package org.anddev.cheesemp.helloandworld;

import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions.ScreenOrientation;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.background.ColorBackground;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.text.Text;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.font.Font;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;
import org.anddev.andengine.util.HorizontalAlign;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

/**
 * @author Nicolas Gramlich
 * @since 11:54:51 - 03.04.2010
 */
public class HelloAndEngine extends BaseGameActivity
```

This sample is from AndEngine but I've had the same issue with every sample I modify. I can't help but feel I've missed something and nothing I found searching has helped.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this.

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".HelloAndEngine">
```

You don't need the fully qualified class name. Also, if you are working with Eclipse and rename a package go to `Project` → `Clean` and let it clean up your project, fixing up references and so on if anything is broken.

Comment: Well, the "." at the beginning will implicitly prepend the full package name.

Comment: @EboMike: Exactly. Why would he need the full package name? He just doesn't.

Comment: True, it's definitely preferred to just use the period. But will this solve the problem? The issue is that the class loader can't find the class org.anddev.cheesemp.helloandworld.HelloAndEngine, which SEEMS to be present.

Comment: @EboMike: True. I forgot to mention that a project cleanup should help.

Comment: Wow, I missed that in the question. Yeah, renaming is bad juju. Cleaning it should do the trick.

Comment: I've tried cleaning several times. The fully qualified name was entered by Eclipse. I originally had .HelloAndEngine before selecting the class with eclipse.

Comment: @cheesemp: What was the old name and what is the new name? I mean the package name.

Comment: Original package name was com.example.helloAndEngine. New name is org.anddev.cheesemp.helloandworld. I have cleared out the old R.java that was generated under the old name. The new R.java is being correctly generated under the new name.

Comment: The error says that your class loader could not load the class `org.anddev.cheesemp.helloandworld.HelloAndEngine`. That means that for whatever reason, this class is not part of your project. Did something really weird happen that caused the .java file not to be part of the project?

Comment: I not sure I have the experience to state that but everything looks ok:

Comment: @cheesemp: Looks very interesting. Where are all the imports from? Doesn't look like you have anything from which it could import stuff.

Comment: Just noticed that the AndEngine wasn't on the export list. I've added it but no effect. Should the Android 2.1 lib also be?

Comment: @Octavian - The AndEngine is a separate project and is marked so in the Java Build Path in Eclipse.

Comment: Its still not fixed but I've marked Octavian's answer as accept because of the effort he's taken to fix the problem. I also think he's probably right in part.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in eclipse android tools
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2824

To Fix -> Right click on the project go to Android tools -> Rename application package..

And also check AndroidManifest.xml if it updated correctly, in my case it didn't, that should solve this problem