# For no reson my Android app stopped running.?

Tags: android, exception

My app has been working fine the whole time I've been developing it, but it suddenly stopped working. It crashes right at the begining even before opening. The same thing happens on the phone or on the emulator. I went back a few versions that used to work as well, and they aren't working.

Could this be something to do with the android.jar??

Here is the LogCat:

```
04-09 23:59:00.065: I/Process(10872): Sending signal. PID: 10872 SIG: 9
04-10 00:01:29.875: D/AndroidRuntime(11072): Shutting down VM
04-10 00:01:29.875: W/dalvikvm(11072): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d560)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.heatscore.pregame/com.heatscore.pregame.appMain}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.heatscore.pregame.appMain in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.heatscore.pregame-1.apk]
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1581)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.heatscore.pregame.appMain in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.heatscore.pregame-1.apk]
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
04-10 00:01:29.875: E/AndroidRuntime(11072):    ... 11 more
```

And here is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.heatscore.pregame"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:theme="@style/app_theme" >
        <activity android:name=".appMain" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="Login"/>
        <activity android:name="MgtRecPredActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="Tabs"/>
        <activity android:name="ScheduleActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="PredictionsActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="ScoreboardActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="AlertsActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="SettingsActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="AboutActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="LogoutActivity"/> 
        <activity android:name="SetPrediction"/> 
        <activity android:name="FinalizePredictionActivity"/>   
        <activity android:name="RegisterAcitvity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>     

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: try cleaning your project. Also have you refactored any objects?

Comment: Check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333516/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-on-my-android-app-but-i-have-no-idea-why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception is a ClassNotFoundException. Eclipse should not compile, if the class is internal to your application. Maybe some external references broken?

Comment: You're right. This was a screw up on my end. I accidental clicked on something while trying to figure out another thing, and somehow all my java file replaced my xml files in the layout folder. Long story short, everything now works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse try 'clean project'