# Getting the latitude and longitude

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

I am trying to get my own location since long but i get some or the other problem..I have asked this question several times.. please help me with this...When i run this app it force closes. Below is the code and log cat.

Code

```
public class MyLocation { 
Timer timer1; 
LocationManager lm; 
LocationResult locationResult; 
boolean gps_enabled=false; 
boolean network_enabled=false; 

public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result) 
{ 
    //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code. 
    locationResult=result; 
    if(lm==null) 
        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 

    //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted. 
    try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){} 
    try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){} 

    //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled 
    if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) 
        return false; 

    if(gps_enabled) 
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps); 
    if(network_enabled) 
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork); 
    timer1=new Timer(); 
    timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000); 
    return true; 
} 

LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() { 
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
        timer1.cancel(); 
        locationResult.gotLocation(location); 
        lm.removeUpdates(this); 
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork); 
    } 
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {} 
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {} 
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {} 
}; 

LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() { 
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
        timer1.cancel(); 
        locationResult.gotLocation(location); 
        lm.removeUpdates(this); 
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps); 
    } 
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {} 
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {} 
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {} 
}; 

class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask { 
    public void run() { 
         lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps); 
         lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork); 

         Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null; 
         if(gps_enabled) 
             gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 
         if(network_enabled) 
             net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER); 

         //if there are both values use the latest one 
         if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){ 
             if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime()) 
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc); 
             else 
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc); 
             return; 
         } 

         if(gps_loc!=null){ 
             locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc); 
             return; 
         } 
         if(net_loc!=null){ 
             locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc); 
             return; 
         } 
         locationResult.gotLocation(null); 
    } 
} 

public static abstract class LocationResult{ 
    public abstract void gotLocation(Location location); 
} 
}
```

Log Cat

```
04-24 11:14:12.692: E/AndroidRuntime(206): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{your.mehul.namespace/your.mel.namespace.MyLocationActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: your.mehul.namespace.MyLocationActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44bfd8d8
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: your.mel.namespace.MyLocationActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44bfd8d8
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
04-24 11:14:12.792: E/AndroidRuntime(206):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your activity in the `AndroidMAnifest.xml`. This problem does not have to do with the gps coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem seems to be that class loader cannot find/load MyLocationActivity. The following Stack Overflow threads can help you solve your problem:

1. [java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688277/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo)
2. [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on my android app but I have no idea why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333516/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-on-my-android-app-but-i-have-no-idea-why)