# Include Android Wheel Kankan project in my own project

Tags: android, picker

i'm trying to include the project mentioned in my android studio project.
The problem is that, beside a 0 error in console, i get "class not found" for every use of the module.
I went to project structure,. than import module, that add dependancies.
Any idea?

Comment: Must check that your library project is also available in your workspace or not. If it is not added then copy it to in your workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean your project and then import it again.

```
Select your project-> goto Project Menu-> and Clean
```

and refer this : [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on my android app but I have no idea why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333516/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-on-my-android-app-but-i-have-no-idea-why)